# MySQL TIME type having hours>23

Tags: mysql

How I can force MySQL display `TIME` columns data from `3.07:10:10` to `79:10:10`?

So the query `SELECT item FROM table_` should return the `TIME` in the `79:10:10` format.

**edit**: `TIME` stores hours, from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.

I tried `SELECT TIME_FORMAT('3.07:10:10', '%H:%i:%s')` and unexpectedly it returns `00:00:03`

Comment: @Perl Dog The only store hours, please see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

Comment: Uhh, sorry, you're right. I really didn't know that. Thought it's only 24hrs. max.

Comment: And then [TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) doesn't work? Like `TIME_FORMAT(item, '%H:%M:%S)`?

Comment: @Perl Dog I am looking for another way to do this (so I can avoid modifying the rest of the code)... e.g. something you set once in the start of the connection and it works on all queries.

Comment: What's the `item`'s datatype? Time?

Comment: @Perl Dog: Yes. I tried `SELECT TIME_FORMAT('3.07:10:10', '%H:%i:%s')` and it returns `00:00:03`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I blamed the OP because I thought `TIME` columns can only store up to 24 hrs. [That's not true](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html): They can store up to ±838 hours. Sorry & thanks for that.)

To insert/use *days* in TIME columns, use the following syntax:

```
mysql> SELECT TIME('3 07:10:10');
+--------------------+
| TIME('3 07:10:10') |
+--------------------+
| 79:10:10           |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

That is: replace the dot in `3.07:10:10` with a blank.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes TIME values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in 'D HH:MM:SS' format. You can also use one of the following “relaxed” syntaxes: 'HH:MM:SS', 'HH:MM', 'D HH:MM', 'D HH',
>     or 'SS'. Here D represents days and can have a value from 0 to 34.
> - ...

If you insert `'3 07:10:10'` into a `TIME` column, it will automatically give `79:10:10` on select.